# SQL stored procedures use condition from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

For this stored procedure, how to add a condition for value `Location`?

If `tblEmployees.Office = USA` and `tblEmployees.state = West` then `Location = CA`, else `Location = others`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spEmployee
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        EmployeeId, Name, Gender, DepartmentName, Location
    FROM 
        tblEmployees
    INNER JOIN 
        tblDepartments ON tblEmployees.EmployeeDepartmentId = tblDepartments.DepartmentId
END
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Syntax and functionality is different between them, so knowing which one you're using is relevant. Please [edit] your post and add a tag for that RDBMS.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple enough `CASE` expression - something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spEmployee
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        EmployeeId, Name, Gender, DepartmentName, 
        Location = CASE
                       WHEN Office = 'USA' AND State = 'West' THEN 'CA'
                       ELSE 'others'
                   END
    FROM 
        tblEmployees e
    INNER JOIN 
        tblDepartments d ON e.EmployeeDepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
END
```